# Can I use an "if" clause without "then"?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

I have the following sentence:

> If T had still been alive, there is the great possibility that either T or C ...

My teacher says that the word "then" must appear after the comma, but I think that it's implied and unnecessary. Who is right?

Comment: I think your teacher was speaking of Visual Basic, not English :)

Comment: ♫ [If you're happy and you know it, clap your hands...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_You%27re_Happy_and_You_Know_It) ♫

Comment: I was always told not to put in "then" when writing documentation as it made it look too much like the code.

Comment: You could start saying this instead: "If, parenthesis, T had still been alive, end parenthesis, curly brace, there is the great possibily that either T or C ..., end curly brace." Just to annoy your teacher [especially if he knows programming]. :)

Comment: It would be interesting if an answer could explain when "then" is to be preferred and when it is not; there is more to it than "it is not required".

Comment: You may use "then" or you may leave it out.  Use it to help with understanding when the "if" clause is long.

Comment: @RegDwighт: If you are happy and you know it, *then* your face will surely show it.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It is not necessary to use *then* to introduce the consequence of the *if* clause:

> If you build it, they will come.
>
> If it ain't broke, don't fix it.
>
> If I give you five dollars a week,
>   you'll have over $250 by the end of
>   the year.

All those are grammatically correct and clear (even the one with *ain't*, which I threw in for a grin.).

Comment: Robusto is correct. Frequently, at least in modern American usage, "then" is associated with someone is being serious or a little upset. e.g. "If you keep drinking, then I want you out of my house." or "If you ate the last banana, then you should have bought more!"

Comment: +1 Absolutely correct. The "then" is often implied in "if" clauses.

Comment: @J.M. If not, then don't. ;)

Comment: As said here @muntoo, the "then" can (usually) be removed with no loss of clarity: "If not, don't" ;D

Answer (score 10):

You can easily answer this backwards.

Consider

> I will go, if you go.

I can simply flip it and say

> If you go, I will go

I don't see myself obligated to write "then" in the second sentence!
If that is true, **then** I should have "then" in the first sentence, too!
Your teacher is probably trying to come up with a reason why he took points off.

Comment: What a mean teacher.

Comment: Do those sentences need commas (- especially the first one)?

Comment: @WAF The first sentence does not require a comma.

Answer (score 9):

You. He/she is just being pedantic.

- http://www.fortunecity.com/bally/durrus/153/gramch28.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence
- http://www.eslhq.com/forums/esl-forums/english-questions/if-then-clause-10627/

Comment: Isn't *overly* pedantic redundant? Wait, was that pedantic of me?

Comment: @webbiedave: possibly. :)

Comment: It does not seem to me that he/she is pedantic, but he/she is just wrong.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Thoug it seems that you can indeed use "then". See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence. It's just that the daily usage usually isn't like that.