# Is using 'then' after 'if', considered informal English?

Tags: formality

A colleague mentioned that while doing exams (in China) for *academic* English, using the word 'then' after an 'if' was marked as incorrect.

For example, "If it is raining then I will need my umbrella" vs "If it is raining, I will need my umbrella".

He thought this was because it was grammatically incorrect, however I have found other questions here that indirectly refute that. For example [Can I use an if clause without then](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/can-i-use-an-if-clause-without-then).

Is this a case of informal vs formal English instead?

Comment: I would say that using *then* after *if* is ***more*** formal, not less—especially in academia in general and logic in particular. But you certainly don't *have* to use *then*. It's a style choice. I'm amazed it would have been marked as incorrect. Perhaps there was a style guide in use that objected to it for some reason. But it's not ungrammatical.

Comment: So it seems to be, neither formal or informal but a question of style.

Answer (score 1):

The fact seems that the *then* is very much there all the time, only it's **elided** more often than not; so much so it may now sound odd to hear the *then* in an *if* conditional.

> **If** Santa Clause was real, (**then**) he would bring me a new bike.

<sup>src: *[If, Then Statements Require Commas](https://www.constant-content.com/content-writing-service/2007/12/if-then-statements-require-commas/)* © Constant Content 2018</sup>